# Bash Script to exit adb logcat

Tags: android, bash, adb, logcat

I am trying to write a script to launch the app and check the logcat for a string. Once I find the string. I want to exit logcat and kill the app

```
if adb shell monkey -p com.app.dev -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1 | adb logcat | grep --line-buffered 'match_text' 
then 
   adb shell am force-stop com.app.dev
fi
```

My script looks something like above. But after I find the matching line in logcat the code in **then** never executes since logcat has taken over the bash command process.

Comment: try `grep -m 1 ...`, thus grep will exit after first match

Comment: @oguzismail that matches the first line found .. but the problem is that "then" clause still not executed as bash has taken over the command prompt by adb logcat and the script never exits

Comment: Why are you using `monkey`? Why are you running `adb logcat` in the pipe when it's not taking any input?

Comment: I could use am instead of monkey .. I am running it in the pipe so that I can match a particular string in adb output when app is launched and then run some other script when that line is found ...

Comment: I dont want to modify the app .. want to do black box testing and montior a value in the logcat output..

Comment: You tried `-m 1` and found it to be ineffective, right?

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this

```
mkfifo temp
# start you app here, I would use am
adb shell monkey -p com.app.dev -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
adb logcat > temp &
pid=$!
if grep -qm1 --line-buffered 'match_text' < temp
then
    kill $pid
    rm temp
    adb shell am force-stop com.app.dev
fi
```